# Override Page module in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, php-5.4

I have override `page Module` means changes the footer pages. So that I have created Page module. but it's displaying empty page.

my code is:

**magento\app\etc\modules\Page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
<Easylife_Page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
           <depends>
                <Mage_Page/>
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Page>
 </modules>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Page\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Page>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_Page>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife_page>
                    <file>page.xml</file>
                </easylife_page>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\layout\page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default translate="label">
        <label>All Pages</label>

        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" />
        </block>


    </default>

</layout>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\template\page\html\footer.phtml**

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
        <p class="bugs"><?php echo $this->__('Frequently Asked Questions') ?> - <a href="faq" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('faq/index/index'); ?>')"><strong><?php echo $this->__('FAQ') ?></strong></a> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this steps are correct or wrong? Please suggest/guide me how to override like all files in `page Module`?

Can any one tell me where I went wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`page.xml` is an already existing layout XML. Please rename to, for example, `easylifepage.xml`.

But since you're only doing minor layout tweaks might I suggest using the `local.xml` in favour of your own extension just to include a layout xml. This will eliminate the need for creating your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you layout xml is called. Put this code instead yours.

```
<default>
    <remove name="header" />
</default>
```

Clear cache. As a result your pages should not contain header.

After you can use this code which is the correct way of customizing page templates

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/header/template.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/footer/template.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</default>
```