# how to override only .phtml files in my custom module in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

I don't want to override `.php` files I want to edit only `.phtml` files of `Page Module`

how can I create layout file and assign?

thanks.

Comment: What is it your custom extension needs to do? If Magento already does what you need, then just to modify the template files in your theme.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko, I just edited my template files but how to create `layout.xml` i.e `page.xml` file. see my actual thread [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16195/override-page-module-in-magento).

Answer (score 4):

to edit the layout use the `local.xml` file in your template. In case it's not there yet you can go ahead and create it.

If you want to have a custom layout file like, for example, `magentonav.xml` you will be required to have your own extension that includes it in the layout.

In case you want to create a new block in your layout with a custom `.phtml` file you can do the following for example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="my_custom_name" template="magentonav/mytemplate.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Notice the type `core/template`. This will allow you to add a `.phtml` file to your layout without requiring you to write your own custom block class

Comment: Same way I fallow your instructions to create my module see my thread is it correct. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16195/override-page-module-in-magento

Comment: I've posted an answer on the question you sent

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to create any module or xml file, just simply copy the file /app/design/frontend/**base/default**/template/page/XXXX.phtml

*to*

/app/design/frontend/**default/default**/template/page/XXXX.phtml

then modify the files under your theme. Magento will overwrite itself.

hit: **default/default** is based on you use the default theme. so change that if you use different theme.