# hide empty attributes from compare product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, compare

How can i hide empty attributes from compare product? is it possible ? if yes how ?
For better understanding i attached image please look in it.

Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153784/magento-1-how-to-hide-empty-or-null-attribute-in-compare-page

Comment: is it solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve this by editing the .phtml file that is generating this view. I suggest that you enable template hints (http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints) to locate which file to change.

Then you just need to check, if the attribute is empty do not display it, something like this could work:

```
if (!empty($product->getData('your_attribute_here'))) {
    echo $product->getData('your_attribute_here');
}
```

If the file that is generating this view is a magento core file, do not hack it, instead create your own .phtml for this in one of your modules. Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16205/5913 for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thanx for you response..
i try to change in app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\compare\list.phtml
but no chance there..

still not touch core files

Comment: Make sure you flush the cache

Comment: Also as far as I know, rwd is part of magento core files (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html) so you should try to create your own version of this file

Comment: Deleted folder Cache from var, also disable all caches from admin.

Comment: it's done.. If want to do then just change code in "This file can be found here:/app/design/frontend/default/[theme name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml"

Comment: I would not recommend this. You're only taking into account the one product. For example lets say product A has colour attribute empty and colour B has the colour attribute set. Aren't you supposed to still compare both attributes? Also you need to take into account the product attribute label.

Answer (score -1):

We have add done this in the list.phtml and is working fine:

```
New line 93
<?php if (!is_null($_item->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_item) != '')): ?>
New line 120
<?php endif; ?>
```

If one of all compared product have something inside the attribute, the line while appear, but you can change "no" in mage_catalog.csv and add "N/A"

Work with Magento 1.9 to 1.9.2.4

Comment: I would not recommend this. You're only taking into account the one product. For example lets say product A has colour attribute empty and colour B has the colour attribute set. Aren't you supposed to still compare both attributes? Also you need to take into account the product attribute label.