# Magento 1 How to Hide Empty or Null Attribute in Compare Page

Tags: magento-1.9, compare

I've realised there are many answer which actually are technically incorrect because they only are taking into account one product. They remove any attribute that is empty or null even if the second product's attribute is not null or empty.

So I decided to post an answer.

Comment: In what folder I can find this block and function?

Comment: @RamaChandranM this is the question. Not an answer.

Comment: I am sorry mistake added comments for thsi :( i will remove it

Comment: How do we implement the accepted answer?

Comment: @HRR1337 following it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to override the block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List` and function `getAttributes()`, this way we have pre sorted array list of attributes instead of having to do the changes at template level.

```
public function getAttributes()
{
  if (is_null($this->_attributes)) {
     $this->_attributes = $this->getItems()->getComparableAttributes();
  }

  // Remove Null Attribute From Compare List
  foreach($this->_attributes as $attribute) {
     $size  = sizeof($this->getItems());
     $count = 0;

     foreach($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $itemAttribute = $item->getData($attribute->getName());
        $trimAttribute = trim($itemAttribute);
        if(is_null($itemAttribute) || empty($trimAttribute)) {
           $count++;
        }

        if($count == $size) {
           unset($this->_attributes[$attribute->getName()]);
        }
     }
  }

  return $this->_attributes;

}
```