# Magento2 - Compare products shows lots of attributes with “N/A”

Tags: attributes, compare

When I compare products on my store, there are a lot of I filled attributes and despite there being no value for each product I’m comparing, it still shows the attribute and a line of `“N/A”` values.

How can I fix this?

It also did show unused values with `“N/A”` on the product page but I edited the

```
attributes.phtml
```

file to fix this. I’m unsure on how I could edit the compare file to solve this though.

Answer (score 1):

See [hide empty attributes from compare product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75096/hide-empty-attributes-from-compare-product?rq=1)

However, the issue of one but not the other being set is not fixed. I couldn't find a fix that was easily accessible.

[Magento 1 How to Hide Empty or Null Attribute in Compare Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153784/magento-1-how-to-hide-empty-or-null-attribute-in-compare-page)

These are from Magento 1 and not Magento 2. I have not tested it but am looking for a solution as well for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

use plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare::getAttributes`

frontend/etc/di.xml:

```
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="[NAME]" type="[VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Plugin\Block\Product\Compare\ListComparePlugin"/>
    </type>
```

VENDOR/MODULE/Plugin/Block/Product/Compare/ListComparePlugin.php

```
public function afterGetAttributes(ListCompare $subject, $result)
{
    foreach ($subject->getItems() as $item) {
        foreach (array_keys($result) as $attributeCode) {
            if (empty(trim($item->getData($attributeCode) ?? ''))) {
                unset($result[$attributeCode]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare using Preference

```
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare"
            type="Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare"/>
```

And update below function

```
/**
 * Retrieve Product Compare Attributes
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAttributes()
{
    if ($this->_attributes === null) {
        $this->_attributes = $this->getItems()->getComparableAttributes();
    }

    // Remove Null Attribute From Compare List
    foreach ($this->_attributes as $attribute) {
        $size  = sizeof($this->getItems());
        $count = 0;

        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemAttribute = $item->getData($attribute->getName());
            $trimAttribute = trim($itemAttribute);
            if (is_null($itemAttribute) || empty($trimAttribute)) {
                $count++;
            }

            if ($count == $size) {
                unset($this->_attributes[$attribute->getName()]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_attributes;
}
```

This is working for me in Magento2